# Tags in Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

In the project's `Web.Config` of MVC, there are tags such as

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider"
            type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            connectionStringName="OfficeData" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
     ...
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
     ...
</roleManager>
```

What are they? And what is their purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Those elements are the basic configuration for [ASP.Net Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.ASPX), the default authentication/authorization system for ASP.Net. There's lots of configuration you'll want to do, but at a high level you have three sets of configuration:

- profile - a system for saving user related profile information (By default a weird data schema is used, and should be avoided)
- membership - the central place for configuring authentication (passwords storage, resetting, etc.)
- roles - your users will be grouped into roles within you app, this is where you configure that

ASP.Net Membership is solid, but dated and inflexible. The new standard is [ASP.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity)